# Key mappings for Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm quite accustomed to the key mappings used in TextWrangler and other editors and I'd like to migrate those mappings into VS Code.

Is it possible to import key mappings from external applications in VS Code?

(Wild card: Failing the above question, does anyone publish key mapping files for VS Code?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install a Keymap extension that brings the keyboard shortcuts from your favorite editor to VS Code. 
Go to `Preferences > Keymap Extensions` to see the current list on the Marketplace.

Reference:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/tips-and-tricks